# How to install valkyrie from old ubuntu repository like Bionic?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, valgrind

Valkyrie is an open-source graphical user interface for the Valgrind 3.6.X line.
Valkyrie uses the Qt widget library, and is based on Valgrind`s XML output capabilities.
Valkyrie is designed for simplicity and ease of use, whilst allowing access to the full range of Valgrind command-line options.

There is no valkyrie package in Ubuntu 20.04's software repositories.
The one I found is https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/valkyrie

This is my second week using linux so I don't know much about it. Is there any available command or script to possibly get this installed?

Comment: Qt4 is EOL and was removed from Ubuntu in 2019 (2015 upstream was announced EOL though Debian & Ubuntu supported it until 15-Mar-2019) ; (for more details refer https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removing-qt-4-from-ubuntu-before-the-20-04-release/12295). The package if maintained should have been ported to Qt5 (introduced 19-Dec-2012) before now. Also note Qt6 is now where all *development* is with Qt5 now in *maintenance* mode though Qt5 EOL hasn't been announced yet, so whatever reason you're wanting a *deprecated* library for should be corrected asap and maybe a security risk.

Comment: Yes Qt4 is available via PPA; but it was removed for a reason, so if security matters to you, consider the reasons for it's removal & alternatives if your box is online...

Comment: @guiverc someone ported it to QT5 https://github.com/rsachetto/valkyrie-qt5 
but running `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` doesn't allow me to `qmake-qt5`

Comment: A Qt5 port of the code would likely be a *safer* option; but don't forget if you're trying to *make` or *compile*, you need the *-dev* packages, and not just *runtime* objects needed for execution.

Comment: anyone who know how to use qt5 to compile? what package should I install first? 
<br>
I already run `sudo apt-get install qt5*-dev` and `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` but
<br>
`qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake': No such file or directory`

Comment: @Eric sudo apt install -y qtcreator qtbase5-dev qt5-qmake cmake